# Use the Comparable Mixin with a Hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I've implemented the [`Comparable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Comparable.html) module in hopes of using it with a hash like so:

```
class Author
  include Comparable
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def <=>(other)
    name.downcase <=> other.name.downcase
  end
end

class Post
  attr_reader :body
  def initialize(body)
    @body = body
  end
end

anthony = Author.new('anthony')
anthony2 = Author.new('anthony')

p anthony == anthony2 # => true

hash = {}
hash[anthony] = [Post.new("one"), Post.new("two")]
p hash
# => {#<Author:0x007fa7481ae6f8 @name="anthony">=>[#<Post:0x007fa7481ade10 @body="one">, #<Post:0x007fa7481add70 @body="two">]}

posts = hash[anthony2]
p posts
# => nil
```

My initial goal was that I could ask for hash values with either `anthony` or `anthony2`.  I thought that because `anthony == anthony2` but clearly that's not true.  Just two questions:

1. How does a hash figure out if a key is `==` to itself?
2. Is there another data structure / ruby class I should be using here or should I implement my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Comparable` module is used for *ordering*. If you want to deal with equivalence for the purpose of hashing you have a little more work to do.

From the documentation on [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html):

> Two objects refer to the same hash key when their `hash` value is identical and the two objects are `eql?` to each other.

So you'll need to extend it a bit more. Since your `@name.downcase` is really important, I've added a variable to capture it to reduce how much computation is required. Repeatedly downcasing the same thing is wasteful, especially when used for comparisons:

```
class Author
  include Comparable
  attr_reader :name
  attr_reader :key
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @key = @name.downcase
  end

  def hash
    @key.hash
  end

  def eql?(other)
    @key.eql?(other.key)
  end

  def <=>(other)
    @key <=> other.key
  end
end
```

Now this works out:

```
Author.new('Bob') == Author.new('bob')
# => true
```

As well as this:

```
h = { }

h[Author.new('Bob')] = true

h[Author.new('bob')]
# => true
```

Comment: Interesting, so while i get `==` for free by implementing `<=>`, I don't get the same equality operator `Hash` is using.  Really great explanation, thanks @tadman

Comment: @Anthony Yeah, you might not need `eql?` explicitly declared like I have here, but `hash` is something you'll need to ensure is determinstic.

Comment: I do in fact need `#eql?` in addition to `<=>`.

Comment: @Anthony I put it in there out of an abundance of caution. Thanks for confirming it's necessary. It's not often you have to write a Hash compatible class, so I try and do it by the book.